# How could we get the full hierarchical data List through Jpa

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

As our data side requirements, there is a mysql table structure like below:

```
id  category_id category_name   parent_id   delete_status
 3  145         Lip Makeup      123           0
 2  134         Face Makeup     123           0
 1  123         Makeup          0             0
```

the data structure is like tree, the recode that id = 1 is father of other 2 records(id = 2 and id = 3). The connection column is `parent_id`, the mapping DTO is :

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "category_tab")
public class CategoryDto {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
private long id;

@Column(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
Long categoryId;

@Column(name = "category_name", nullable = false)
String name;

@Column(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
Long parentId;

@Column(name = "delete_status", nullable = false)
Integer deleteStatus;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Set<CategoryDto> children = new HashSet<>();

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    ShopeeCategoryDto that = (ShopeeCategoryDto) o;
    return Objects.equals(categoryId, that.categoryId) &&
            Objects.equals(name, that.name);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(categoryId, name);
}}
```

Now I want to get full list of CategoryDto which contains its children list cause it can be easily handled subsequently. like as DaoImpl:

```
List<CategoryDto> fetchAll();
```

So how should I implements this method? I used spring boot + Jpa framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Query("select category from CategoryDto category where category.deleteStatus != ?1")
CategoryDto findAllBydeleteStatus(Integer deleteStatus);
```

Docs : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

Comment: it's just an example, not what I need, I had removed it

Comment: With this method, you will get all the categoryDtos along with set of its parents categoryDto where deleteStatus is not one supplied in function parameter.

Comment: understood, let me try